# Should we add a notify/follow a question feature?

Tags: feature-request

I have come across many questions that I want to know answer of to. But All I do is favourite the question. So I want to make a suggestion to the community to add a feature that would notify me about any new answers added to the questions. So that I don't have to check the question every day from my favorites page.

I think this would be more efficient and productive! Please present your opinion. :D

Answer (score 4):

This was proposed about 5 years ago on Meta Stack Exchange<sup>1</sup>:

[Adding Favorites to the Stack Exchange global inbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83343/adding-favorites-to-the-stack-exchange-global-inbox)

I think if you follow [this list of related/duplicate questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/83343?sort=newest), the story is that this *was* implemented at one point, but people actually hated the idea and they *removed* the feature. I somewhat doubt it'll come back, despite the continued requests for it.

<sup>It was probably actually asked on Meta Stack Overflow before MSE was created, but that's neither here nor there</sup>

Comment: Curious what the downvote is meant here.

Answer (score -2):

### We have a favorite feature for questions already.

Below the voting arrows on a question you'll see a star icon (this is on the full site, the mobile app does not have this interface). That is the control for the favorite feature.

[image]

Access to your favorited questions is found in your profile.

[image]

### We use RSS for following.

Questions, tags and users all have RSS feeds at the bottom right of the layout in the full site (again, the mobile app is more limited).

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'll have to check the feed anyways .. That is what I want to automate.. To Get a notification for that

Comment: The android mobile app has a favorite button, it's at the bottom of the post near Edit, Share & More.